# Outlook 2013 and Windows key hook using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: outlook, vsto, hook, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to build a single key shortcut for Outlook following the code from here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/08/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx

It works fine for outlook 2010 but for outlook 2013 is not working
The hook is there, if you press the key on other windows my code gets invoked but only when the Outlook 2013 window has the focus is not working

Same issue like here: [C# Outlook 2013 Add-In Keyboard Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647898/c-sharp-outlook-2013-add-in-keyboard-events)
or similar with this one
[C# Global keyboard hook in Office Addin 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401953/c-sharp-global-keyboard-hook-in-office-addin-2013)

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: Are you trying to override existing keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: no, no overrides to existing shortcuts

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635463/i-have-a-vsto-application-as-an-add-in-to-ms-word-and-i-want-to-set-keyboard-sho/9840871#9840871

Comment: Thanks Kiru, Looks good but in my case is a single key press do something , not a combination of keys